# SSIS Validation error in Integration Service Catalogs

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, odata

I'm new to SSIS OData. I have a problem when I am trying to execute the SSIS package from SQL Server Management Studio, or call it from a SQL Server Agent job, but it is working fine when I execute it from Visual Studio 2015.

This is the error returned from when I return the execution report:

[image: Integration Services Catalog Message]

Comment: How are you calling the SSIS from c#?

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for comment, I created .dtx package in c# then I deployed it to the SQL  Integration Services Catalog and I called this service from SQL Job

Comment: It may be a credential issue.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/execute-package-utility-dtexecui-ui-reference?view=sql-server-ver15